# Deleted queue is not redefined, consumers stop to handle messages

Tags: spring-amqp

I'm trying to solve following problem:

1. I have 2 SimpleMessageListenerContainer defined in java conf.
2. Each of them has it's own listener wrapped with adapter and they both use same CachingConnectionFactory(is it ok?). In addition each of them handles different queue(with constant name)
3. I'm testing scenario when for whatever reason one of the queues is deleted.
4. When I'm deleting it manually from web admin console the container tries to redefine this queue and fails(all retries fail). The exception is not really tells the reason of the failure.
5. Eventually all the consumer threads of this queue are "restarted" however they wont consume any messages further. Even though somebody else will redefine this queue(e.g. producer)

so there are several questions:

1. Can I fix redefinition of the queue somehow, or check why the redefinition fails? On fresh start the definition of queues works. Which brings me to next question
2. Might be I can make heartbeat sender to use daemon thread somehow? It prevents jvm from exiting, so the restart isn't happening. It won't solve problem, but fresh jvm process succeeds to redefine queues. Restart will be caused by supervisor.

Meanwhile I'm getting situation when all consumers(under first container) for deleted queue are not really working, I'd expect that jvm will exit, however probably since I have second container which is ok(all consumers alive and queue exists), the jvm continues to live(might be when second container will be shutdown the heartbeat sender also will stop?)

any suggestions will be appreciated. If needed I'll post code snippets of java configuration.

Comment: Add some code which should define the Queue and the definition of it. Are you using spring-boot? Any virtual host configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We just "fixed" this by adding a `missing-queues-fatal` attribute to the listener container.

[See the pull request here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/190).

We can't make schema changes in point releases so there's a couple of ways to configure it in 1.3.x; it has been added to the schema in 1.4.x and will be available in `<rabbit:listener-container/>`; you can see the [1.4.x Pull Request here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-amqp/pull/192).

1.3.5 should be available later this week, or next, but you can try `1.3.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT` now if you want.

When it is set to false (default true), the container will go into recovery mode, using the `recovery-interval`.

[Documentation for the 1.3.5. snapshot is here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/1.3.5.BUILD-SNAPSHOT/reference/html/whats-new.html#d4e166).

Comment: thanks a lot Gary for the quick response. I'll wait for the 1.3.5 I have few weeks before going to prod. As far as I understand if I'll put missingQueuesFatal = false, then eventually when queue is created the recovery process will success to "recover". As aside question do you have any suggestions how to turn off all other containers when only one of them enters recovery mode?

Comment: Yes, currently it tries 3 times and gives up (stops the container), but the JVM doesn't exit. You can manually restart the container by calling its `start()` method after the queues have been re-created. You can also force the `RabbitAdmin` to recreate the queues by calling its `initialize()` method (you don't need 1.3.5 for either of these features). There is currently no way to get notified that a container is in recovery mode, without examining the log.

Comment: As a general comment - you shouldn't really delete queues when there are active consumers :)  Note, however, if at least 1 queue is designated as `auto-delete` everything *will* automatically be re-declared by the container when it starts (or goes into recovery mode). We have been thinking about doing this for any queue type, but that would be a 1.4 feature (and a few months away).

Comment: yes, I know :) It was my way of simulating some broker failure...I'll try some kind of stop-delay-start sequence instead. Can I open improvement suggestions? I have currently two: some listener on every container when it stopped(IMO it's important when there are few in one jvm) and second: give possibility to make heartbeat sender to use daemon thread. Anyway thanks a lot for your responses!

Comment: It's not clear to me exactly what you are asking for, but certainly you can open new feature/improvement issues on our JIRA (https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP). Please be clear and provide as much information as possible.