# Exceptions in rabbitmq with spring boot

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, spring-rabbit

I am getting the following exception repeatedly when I start my spring boot application with rabbitmq. The entire flow is working fine even with the below exceptions. is it to do with the auto-delete in by means ?

```
    08 Jul 2015 16:20:17,652 [ERROR] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-2] SimpleMessageListenerContainer| Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
    java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:111)
        at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:621)
        at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:665)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:208)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:444)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1035)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1028)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1004)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:254)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$300(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
        at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1081)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

08 Jul 2015 16:52:47,148 [WARN ] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer| Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:111)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:621)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:665)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:444)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:434)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1083)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

the following are my beans

```
 <rabbit:queue id="reportQueue" name="reportQueue" durable="true" auto-delete="false" exclusive="false"/>


 <rabbit:direct-exchange id="reportExchange" durable="true" name="reportExchange">
     <rabbit:bindings>
        <rabbit:binding queue="reportQueue" key="reportBind"></rabbit:binding>
     </rabbit:bindings>
 </rabbit:direct-exchange>


  <bean id="aListener" class="com.sample.ReportMessageListener" autowire="byName"/>
  <bean id="reportMessageConverter" class="com.sample.ReportMessageConverter"/>
 <rabbit:listener-container id="myListenerContainer" connection-factory="connectionFactory" acknowledge="auto" prefetch="5" concurrency="1" message-converter="reportMessageConverter" >
    <rabbit:listener ref="aListener" queues="reportQueue"/>
</rabbit:listener-container>
```

**Update:**

with debug enabled the messages are

```
09 Jul 2015 14:46:35,284 [DEBUG] [main] SimpleMessageListenerContainer| Starting Rabbit listener container.
09 Jul 2015 14:46:38,601 [DEBUG] [elasticsearch[local_jvm_node][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]] service                  | [local_jvm_node] processing [routing-table-updater]: execute
09 Jul 2015 14:46:38,602 [DEBUG] [elasticsearch[local_jvm_node][clusterService#updateTask][T#1]] service                  | [local_jvm_node] processing [routing-table-updater]: no change in cluster_state
09 Jul 2015 14:46:40,324 [ERROR] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer| Failed to check/redeclare auto-delete queue(s).
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:111)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:621)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:665)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:444)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:1035)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1028)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:1004)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:254)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.redeclareElementsIfNecessary(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:963)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$300(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:83)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1081)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
09 Jul 2015 14:46:40,328 [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer    | Starting consumer Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=MANUAL local queue size=0
09 Jul 2015 14:46:45,333 [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer| Recovering consumer in 5000 ms.

09 Jul 2015 14:46:50,402 [WARN ] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer| Consumer raised exception, processing can restart if the connection factory supports it
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.get(BlockingCell.java:77)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingCell.uninterruptibleGet(BlockingCell.java:111)
    at com.rabbitmq.utility.BlockingValueOrException.uninterruptibleGetValue(BlockingValueOrException.java:37)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel$BlockingRpcContinuation.getReply(AMQChannel.java:367)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:621)
    at com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory.newConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:665)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:444)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils$1.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:80)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.doGetTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:130)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.getTransactionalResourceHolder(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:67)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.BlockingQueueConsumer.start(BlockingQueueConsumer.java:434)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1083)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
09 Jul 2015 14:46:50,403 [INFO ] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] SimpleMessageListenerContainer| Restarting Consumer: tags=[{}], channel=null, acknowledgeMode=MANUAL local queue size=0
09 Jul 2015 14:46:50,403 [DEBUG] [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1] BlockingQueueConsumer    | Closing Rabbit Channel: null
```

Comment: see if this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24373588/deleted-queue-is-not-redefined-consumers-stop-to-handle-messages

Comment: did you ever get this resolved?  what was the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Restarting RabbitMQ resolved this for me (Mac).

```
cd /usr/local/sbin 
./rabbitmqctl stop_app
./rabbitmqctl start_app
```

Comment: is there something wrong with the rabbitMQ, which is causing the issue?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with auto-delete queues (except the fact that you have some means the container is initializing the connection at this particular point in its lifecycle).

You seem to have some network issues...

```
java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException
....
    at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection.start(AMQConnection.java:293)
```

The rabbitmq client library has a hard-coded 5 second timeout when waiting for the response for the connection start command and the server is not replying in time.

Comment: i am running the client and rabbitmq on the same machine. and even with these error messages(these messages are continuous and not a one-time) producer and consumer are passing the messages fine. if this is a connection problem I believe the whole thing should nt be working. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: Perhaps the problems are transient? If you turn on DEBUG logging you should get a lot more information. I know the timeout stuff was only recently added to the rabbit client that is used by Spring AMQP so there might be some new issue there; a DEBUG log should help. If it's too big to post here, try pastebin or a github gist.

Comment: Yes the problem is transient. But I am getting these 8 out of 10 times i start my application. Added the messages with debug enabled in the question. Please let me know if you need any thing. Mean time, I am trying to investigate this by trying some other properties.

Comment: Nothing obvious from the logs. See if there is anything in the rabbitmq logs.

Comment: I'd like to see a more complete log - including when the app starts working.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is about your spring-rabbit version.
I encountered the same problem as you. but I have no idea to fix it.
But in my another project, it works well. Then I compared two projects.
I discovered the spring-rabbit version is different from each other.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

this new version throw TimeoutException.
but

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.amqp</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-rabbit</artifactId>
  <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

this version it works well.
my spring-boot version is "Camden.SR2".default spring-rabbit 1.6.5.RELEASE.

Hope it helps you

Answer (score 1):

I think you can try to change the port to 5672, it works for me

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try overriding the default handshakeTimeout by defining bean

```
com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory#setHandshakeTimeout
```

Something like below:

```
<bean id="myConnectionFactory" class="com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory"
      p:automaticRecoveryEnabled="false" p:handshakeTimeout="${rabbit.handshakeTimeout:10000}">
 ....
</bean>
```